# Is it possible to use a join-like function either in Hiera or Puppet?

Tags: dictionary, puppet, hiera

I got a list of IPs in a yaml file:

```
---
ips:
  1.1.1.1
  2.2.2.2
  3.3.3.3
```

Furthermore the IPs are used (interpolated) in another variable

```
params:
  value: "%{hiera('ips')}"
```

This works so far. The content is `1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3`

In a module I need to join each of these ips with a comma so it looks like this:

```
1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3
```

I tried to do this with `map` and `each` but I am not quite sure how to apply this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ip's in `hiera` is an `array` then you can use the `join` function from [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib). eg:

```
---
ips:
  - 1.1.1.1
  - 2.2.2.2
  - 3.3.3.3
```

In your manifest:

```
$joined = join(hiera('ips'), ",")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works so far in puppet, but it seems to not be possible to join data from `value: "%{hiera('ips')}"` as it always is a string-type. I would like to see someone to prove that it might be possible.

Comment: That's because you are interpolating. It will always be a string if that is the case.